# IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when reading/writing large bytestring

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I'm getting

```
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

when I try to write a large bytestring to disk with `f.write()`, where `f` was opened with mode `wb`.

I've seen lots of people online getting this error when using a Windows network drive, but I'm on OSX (10.7 when I originally asked the question but 10.8 now, with a standard HFS+ local filesystem). I'm using Python 3.2.2 (happens on both a python.org binary and a homebrew install). I don't see this problem with the system Python 2.7.2.

I also tried mode `w+b` based on [this Windows bug workaround](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;899149), but of course that didn't help.

The data is coming from a large numpy array (almost 4GB of floats). It works fine if I manually loop over the string and write it out in chunks. But because I can't write it all in one pass, `np.save` and `np.savez` fail -- since they just use `f.write(ary.tostring())`. I get a similar error when I try to save it into an existing HDF5 file with `h5py`.

Note that I get the same problem when reading a file opened with `file(filename, 'rb')`: `f.read()` gives this `IOError`, while `f.read(chunk_size)` for reasonable `chunk_size` works.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Weird.  `EINVAL`=22, but nothing in [`man 2 write`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man2/write.2.html) looks applicable.  Can you run under [`dtruss`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) to check if it's really the `write` syscall that's failing?

Comment: "It works fine if I manually loop over the string and write it out in chunks." so why don't you? How large of a chunk of data do you think you should be able to write at a time? More than you can count with a `size_t`?

Comment: @msw Like I said, this breaks `np.save` and more importantly for me `h5py`. Obviously if I'm doing it manually, I can and do write it in chunks, and it works in `h5py` if I create the dataset first and write, say, 50 rows at a time. But this shouldn't be necessary, as evidenced by the fact that both of those libraries don't see the need to do that. And my arrays are "only" 500 million entries (log_2 < 29), which is addressable by a 32-bit `int`, let alone a `size_t`.

Comment: @ephemient Thanks for the suggestion. I put a test script and its dtruss output [here](https://gist.github.com/3196462) (attached while the script was in "generating output"). The error "out of scratch space in action #12 at DIF offset 44" seems pretty suspicious, but I'm not 100% sure how to interpret this. My desktop has 8GB of ram, which during generation at least is mostly but not completely full -- this seems to be implying that something is trying to make a full copy during the write action? Note that the output file is created but empty.

Comment: That error looks like a `dtruss` failure -- instead of truncating long strings like `strace`, it just fails to buffer the syscall info. :( Still, this clearly fingers the `write` syscall, for whatever that's worth. I wonder what the `0x601` flags to `open` mean; `1` is conventionally `O_WRONLY`, but I can't look up `0x200` and `0x400` without OS X headers.  If one of them is `O_DIRECT` then that's a potential cause for write failures, but IIRC that flag doesn't exist on OS X... still confused.

Comment: @ephemient `0x200` is `O_CREAT` and `0x400` is `O_TRUNC` in my `/usr/include/sys/fcntl.h`.

Comment: it might be unrelated but there is MAX_RW_COUNT (a single read()/write() system call won't read/write more than that) on Linux that was as small as 2147479552 in some cases.

Comment: Could you not create a file-wrapper that "chunked" large read or write requests into multiple pieces small enough to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a general OSX bug with fread / fwrite and so isn't really fixable by a Python user. See [numpy #3858](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3858), [this torch7 commit](https://github.com/torch/torch7-distro/commit/40e65934e071e452f194a9d8c0fd740131babefa), [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938180/344821), ....

Supposedly it's been fixed in Mavericks, but I'm still seeing the issue.

Python 2 may have worked around this or its io module may have always buffered large reads/writes; I haven't investigated thoroughly.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps try not opening with the b flag, I didn't think that was supported on all OS / filesystems.

Comment: The `b` flag is necessary for [binary mode](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open), which means in python 3 that it handles bytes instead of strings. What you're probably thinking of is that `b` was a no-op on Unix platforms in Python 2, which is no longer the case.

Comment: Also, just to make sure, I just tried it (opening the file with mode `w` and doing `f.write(the_bytestring.decode('latin1'))` to output gibberish based on the true bytestring; got the same IOError 22.