# IOError writing very large file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python module that is responsible for doing some preprocessing/tokenizing on a dataset that I want to use.  The dataset is a 144M line text file that I read into memory, split into different pieces, shuffle, then write to new files.  Previously, writing was done by the following function:

```
def write_lines(filename, lines):
with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

When trying to do this on the 144M line dataset, I get the `IOError: [Errno 22]` error.  However, there are no issues running the exact same code on a 6M line dataset.  Before sending the dataset to this module, it is ran through a filtering service that ensures only the characters matching the pattern `[\x00-\x7f]` are in the file, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008422/how-to-remove-high-ascii-characters-from-string-like-in-java).

I am running python2.7 in an Anaconda environment.  Some of the code I am using came from an open source project that performs some complicated string processing logic that does not work on Python3 no matter what I have tried, so switching to Python3 is not an option (if that would even help).

Is there any way a larger dataset could be causing this error?  I would  have thought that the only thing that could go wrong is a memory error but `Errno 22` does not seem to have anything to do with memory.

Comment: Can the filter step be done separately and before shuffling?

Comment: Are you on OSX by any chance? If you are, look at this [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662960/ioerror-errno-22-invalid-argument-when-reading-writing-large-bytestring)

Comment: @Jakub Yes I am running the code on an iMac.

Comment: @AlexReynolds no, the filtering is done in a separate Java module (along with a lot of other logic) that depends on pre-existing java classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to join your lines in one big line. You are probably getting a line that is too long. Try this:

```
def write_lines(filename, lines):
    with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
        for line in lines:
            fout.write(line + '\n')
```

And look through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141761/region-ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-w-or-filename).

Comment: Or possibly more succinctly: `fout.writelines(line + '\n' for line in lines)`